# How to export logstash data to external database

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've setup logstash instance ,and github logs are forwarding to this logstash instance. I am in need of run the query to fetch the information from logstash like database query.

Please let me know how to connect logstash to oracle database and get those logstash info from DB

thanks

Comment: Are you running Logstash with Elasticsearch in embedded mode? Or how/where are you actually storing the logs?

Comment: hi, yes, I am running the logstash with elastic search in embedded mode.  I want to run the query and retrieve data like from DB , I am not sure how to do it via logstash or elastic search , thanks

Comment: Your making me want to cry for you.  Don't put the data in Oracle, learn to query ElasticSearch.  ElasticSearch was built for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query elasticsearch directly via the API - look at the examples in the API documentation here, http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search.html

If you have the logs being captured with a specific 'type', you could do something like:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?q=type:github&size=50'
```

which would search the logstash indices for anything with type 'github' and return the first 50 entries.

Comment: thanks. I am already getting the output as you given URL. However I am looking at connect the logstash with oracle database and and get the needed fields by running the query . example get the user transaction in github  using the transaction_id or user_id in query.

Comment: If you really need to output to Oracle, you're probably going to need some code to parse the results from the API and feed that to Oracle.
Alternatively, someone is creating an logstash output filter to feed to jdbc @ https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc not sure if this would work?

Comment: thank you, I'll try this way to connect logstash to oracle DB